# Parallel for loop to add points to series resulting in index outside the bounds of array

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, mschart

```
int signal_length=1000_000;
double[] x=new double[signal_length];

var Signal = new Series
{
    IsVisibleInLegend = true,
    ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
    LegendText = "Original Signal",
};

var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };
Parallel.For(0, x.Length,options, i =>
{
  Signal.Points.AddY(x[i]);
});

chart.Series.Add(Signal);
```

Error message:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

I think this error arise as the parallel loop not atomic
I want something like "REDUCTION" in c++

Comment: It should be x.Length/4 for each Parallel process.  The starting point 0 would also have to change.

Comment: What is `Signal.Points`?

Comment: My guess is that the exception happens inside `Points.AddY`. Please comfirm this suspicion by posting the stacktrace of the exception. If yes, then post the source code of the `AddY` method. It it most likely not implemented thread-safe,

Comment: @jdweng how i can implement this?

Comment: @NineBerry Points.AddY it's function in chart control that add points to series to draw it

Comment: Control of which framework?

Comment: The posted code does not look like it’s even suitable for parallelism.. Parallel.For is not “reduce”, so not sure how the claimed goal is even shown.

Comment: @jdweng Nope, `Parallel.For(0, x.Length, ...` is correct

Comment: @Reniuz DotNet :`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series`
my problem in the parallel for loop not in the methods

Comment: Why do you assume that `Signal.Points.AddY` is threadsafe? It doesn't make sense that a chart series would be threadsafe. The order is one of the most important thing in a chart

Answer (score 1):

The chart control is not thread-safe. You cannot simply call functions of it from multiple threads in parallel.

Use the [`DataBindY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.databindy) method to add multiple data points at once. To improve performance, the `DataBind*` methods use `SuspendUpdates` / `ResumeUpdates` internally to prevent the chart from being redrawn while data points are being added.

It will not be possible to improve performance over how Microsoft has implemented their `DataBind*` methods.

---

Performance measurement:

```
double[] x = new double[1_000_000];
Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    x[i] = r.NextDouble();
}

var Signal = new Series
{
    IsVisibleInLegend = true,
    ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
    LegendText = "Original Signal",
};

DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

Signal.Points.DataBindY(x);

DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

MessageBox.Show((end - start).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
```

This code shows that this takes ~ 1600ms on my computer for adding the datapoints using `DataBindY`. I don't see how you could improve this part.

If you are seeing slow performance for the actual drawing of the chart, you will have to look for improvements by reducing the amount of data points. For example limit the number of points altogether or only include every n.th datapoint.

Comment: Actually x values was read from binary file
I want to add them in parallel fashion to save time
I can bind them once but in sequential mode using `Signal.Points.DataBindY(x)`

Comment: @Dev.Mahmood Okay, this is not possible. The chart control is not thread-safe. There is no way to speed-up adding values by parallelization, only by adding all values at once.

Comment: @Reniuz sure i read the file in parallel, but it's huge more than 1 million value it take about 10 second to draw it